# $S:=\cup_{m,n\in\mathbb Z}T_{m,n}$ in $\mathbb R^2$, $T_{m,n}$ is the st-line joining origin and the point $(m,n).$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the following set dense in $\mathbb R^2$? How to show:

> > $S:=\cup_{m,n\in\mathbb Z}T_{m,n}$ in $\mathbb R^2$,
> >
> > $T_{m,n}$ is the st-line joining origin and the point $(m,n).$

Comment: Draw a ball of radius $r$ around some point $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. Does it intersect some line $T_{m,n}$?

Comment: I cant understand. Intuitively there should be a line...

Comment: Can you find a point $(u,v)$ "very close" to $(x,y)$ with $u,v \in \mathbb Q$?

Comment: So, basically I had to think $\mathbb Q^2$ dense in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: Yeah, exactly - but the idea was not to give it away! :)

Comment: sure.............:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $r=\frac{a}{b}$ and $s=\frac{c}{d}$ are rational numbers, then setting $m=ad$ and $n=bc$ we get
$$ nr=bc\frac{a}{b}=ac=ad\frac{c}{d}=ms$$

Therefore the point $(r,s)$ lies on the line $my-nx=0$, which is precisely the line $T_{m,n}$.

Thus $S$ contains the set $D$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with rational coordinates, and as $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it follows that $S$ is dense as well.